# Create repository when EntityRepository is deprecated typeorm

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I usually use this code to create a repository:

```js
import { EntityRepository, Repository } from 'typeorm'
import { User } from './user.entity'
    
@EntityRepository(User)
export class UserRepository extends Repository<User> {
  getInactiveUsers(): Promise<User[]> {
    return this.createQueryBuilder()
      .where('isActive = :active', { active: false })
      .getMany()
  }
}
```

However, now `EntityRepository` is deprecated. I found a [reference](https://gist.github.com/anchan828/9e569f076e7bc18daf21c652f7c3d012) but I think it's quite complex. I wonder if there is a simpler way to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is deprecated, you can create custom repository with DataSource, you can read [this](https://typeorm.io/custom-repository#how-to-create-custom-repository).

Comment: not working "Property 'getRepository' does not exist on type 'typeof DataSource'"

Answer (score 1):

for the time being syntax below works for me:

```
const queryBuilder = AppDataSource.getRepository(Post).createQueryBuilder("post");
```

I hope this helps

https://typeorm.io/select-query-builder#what-is-querybuilder

Answer (score -2):

But if you want to continue using the Repository class you can roll back to the next version and continue using this feature.

```
"typeorm": "0.2.45",
"@nestjs/typeorm": "8.0.3",
```

Use NPM:

```
npm i @nestjs/typeorm@8.0.3 typeorm@0.2.45
```

without ^

Comment: This is not possible when you have @nestjs/common in version 9.X as a dependency.